# Removing Edit Access from a Sheet using email from a cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how to remove someone from a spreadsheet using google app scripts.

Essentially, I have a central spreadsheet with information such as emails, names, UID's etc on it. I am trying to pull the email from this spreadsheet and use the removeEditor function to remove that email from another spreadsheet. You can view the code below.

```
        var officerIDrow = officerID + 1;

    var Tracker = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('P_Tracker'); //the button is on the same sheet as this, this is why it is get active.

    var PTBooking = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1JPS69ko99dQTEwjplF_l2l2G_T8RyHjxCyMxXd_AV_s"); //Referring to the other sheet where the email will be removed from editors.

    var EmailAddressRange = "F" + officerIDrow; //This is the column where the emails are stored. The officer ID row refers to the user inputted value in a dialog. Don't worry about this, I have already checked to see if this is the issue,

    var EmailAddress1 = Tracker.getRange(EmailAddressRange);

    var EmailAddress2 = EmailAddress1.getValue();

    var EmailAddress3 = Utilities.formatString(EmailAddress2); //In my desperation, I was trying to see if setting it as string would help.

    PTBooking.removeEditor(EmailAddress3);
```

This isn't the full version of the code. If you'd like to see it, you can click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B97zCil2wco-RENMbUg3bnVqQ00/view?usp=sharing). But all that matters is above, everything else works fine.

The code above runs fine until it hits the last line where it tries to remove the email. The error message that appears says: "Invalid email: ". I'm assuming after the "email:" bit, it should display what has been pulled. But it doesn't! I have no idea why it isn't finding and using the email to remove people.

Can anyone spot any issues?

Thanks,

Shaun.

Comment: Hi,
have you tried manually declaring a var as a know editor email address and see if it works?

Have you  tried using getEditors to see what it returns and how it returns it.

In var tracker you use single quotes. ' ' ,  but in others you use double " ". Perhaps stick to one and see. 

I know you say don't worry about emailAddressRange, but if it was me, I'd be looking at that too.

Comment: By just doing, PTBooking.removeEditor("tommy.369@live.co.uk");  that doesn't work. I have no idea on how to even refer to the other spreadsheet properly.

Comment: I tried something like this.
`function myTest() {
var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID HERE");
var editors = ss.getEditors();
ss.removeEditor("an@email.com");
Logger.log(editors);
}`

This logged email address of editors fine and removed the selected editor from an external spreadsheet.
I'd be interested to see what your `emailAddress2` logs to the logger.

Comment: I suppose I could do that, however, I would have to put that into an array to refer to. I'll try it out now.

Comment: This was just a quick test to see if removeEditor worked with an email hardcoded. Now we can see it is, I'd be looking at exactly how your email is created in the code. Are there any spaces, etc.

Comment: You also mention the "email:" bit in your original question. Is your email stored as `email: a@a.com` in the cell? removeEditor takes a user or email address. So that would explain why it's not working

Answer (score 0):

This basic test worked for me. It could read email address from the spreadsheet then remove editors from the external sheet. I tried to copy your example, but I don't know how the officerIDrow works, but I assume it's a number. So just stored a number as a var

```
function myTest() {
var ss  = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID HERE");
var idRow = 11;
var tracker = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("tracker");
var emailCell = "F"+idRow;
Logger.log(emailCell);
var emailAddress = tracker.getRange(emailCell).getValue();
Logger.log(emailAddress);

ss.removeEditor(emailAddress);

var editors = ss.getEditors();
Logger.log(editors);

}
```

I've left the Logger bits in as it will help point you at what script is doing at each point.

The email address in the cell must be plain, such as google@google.com

Comment: Hello Munkey, I have made a video which you can find at this link:https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B97zCil2wco-eTlLYkgxXzBmYnc&usp=sharing            which explains everything

Comment: I'm on the iPad at the moment so managed to view your video and can see what your getting at. I'd be really interested to fill up column f with f and the row number and test what's being returned. Can't really offer much more help tonight but if you're free for a google hangout tomorrow let me know. I'm no expert at scripting btw just trying to help.